# Integrating a 2D Array into a Calendar Printing Program

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2019

I've decided to start learning to code on my own from a C++ textbook and one of the challenges is to create a program that prints the calendar of a given year, in this style for each month:

```
-------------January-------------

Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
                          1    2
 3    4    5    6    7    8    9
10   11   12   13   14   16   17
18   19   20   21   22   23   24
25   26   27   28   29   30   31
```

I have the whole program written out here in Microsoft Visual Studio, but another one of the challenges is to then convert the data from the two 1D arrays from the getMonthName and dayNumber function into one function with a 2D array that gathers both the month name and the day number, using this array:

```
// the first number is the month and second number is the last day of the month. 
int yearly[12][2] = 
{{1,31},{2,28},{3,31},{4,30},{5,31},{6,30},{7,31},{8,31},{9,30},{10,31},{11,30},{12,31}};
```

The textbook doesn't explain 2D arrays very well, but I know the basics. I just don't know how to go about referencing the contents of the array. Can I assign all the "month number" values of the array to a variable, like I have here for the variable monthNumber, and just go from there? If someone could perhaps provide an example on how one would do this, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm trying to absorb as much information as I can, so if you could explain how your example works as well, I'd be over the moon.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year)
{

    static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1,
                       4, 6, 2, 4 };
    year -= month < 3;
    return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 +
        year / 400 + t[month - 1] + day) % 7;
}


string getMonthName(int monthNumber)
{
    string months[] = { "January", "February", "March",
                       "April", "May", "June",
                       "July", "August", "September",
                       "October", "November", "December"};

    return (months[monthNumber]);
}

//number of days in month
int numberOfDays(int monthNumber, int year)
{
    // january
    if (monthNumber == 0)
        return (31);

    // february
    if (monthNumber == 1)
        return (28);

    // march
    if (monthNumber == 2)
        return (31);

    // april
    if (monthNumber == 3)
        return (30);

    // may
    if (monthNumber == 4)
        return (31);

    // june
    if (monthNumber == 5)
        return (30);

    // july
    if (monthNumber == 6)
        return (31);

    // august
    if (monthNumber == 7)
        return (31);

    // september
    if (monthNumber == 8)
        return (30);

    // october
    if (monthNumber == 9)
        return (31);

    // november
    if (monthNumber == 10)
        return (30);

    // december
    if (monthNumber == 11)
        return (31);
}

// display calendar function
void printCalendar(int year)
{
    printf ("         Calendar - 2021", year);
    int days;

    // day from 0 - 6
    int current = dayNumber(1, 1, year);


    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        days = numberOfDays(i, year);

        // current month display
        printf("\n  ------------%s-------------\n",
               getMonthName(i).c_str());

        //columns
        printf("  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

        // spaces
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < current; k++)
            printf("     ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= days; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", j);

            if (++k > 6)
            {
                k = 0;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        if (k)
            printf("\n");

        current = k;
    }

    return;
}

// main function
int main()
{
    int year = 2021;
    printCalendar(year);

    return (0);
}
```

Please let me know if you need any more info, I'll be happy to provide more.

Comment: What is `t`? Why is it `static`? What do you think the line `year -= month < 3;` is doing? Did you verify that return expression performs the operations in the order you want it to? I have a question about almost every line in your first function, I guess.

Comment: @sweenish This is the algorithm for calculating the date. I found a related description. `In 1970, John Horton Conway came up with an algorithm, often termed the “Doomsday Algorithm.” This algorithm uses the formula: (d+m+y+[y/4]+c ) mod 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared a global variable `int yearly[12][2];`

snippet line 90:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        days = numberOfDays(i, year);
        yearly[i][0] = i; //month
        yearly[i][1] = days;//days
        ... ...
```

The **for** loop is executed 12 times, and each **i** corresponds to a month.

Yearly [i][**0**] is the month  and yearly [i][**1**] is the days of the month.

What a 2D array looks like:

```
          column
   Row 0 [0][1]
       1 [0][1]
       2 [0][1]
        ... ...
       11[0][1]
```

Example of printing a 2D array：

```
 for (int Row= 0; Row< 12; Row++)
    {
        std::cout << "{";
        for (int column= 0; column< 2; column++)
        {
            std::cout << yearly[Row][column]<<",";
        }
        std::cout << "}"<<std::endl;
    }
```